# Append new line to CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to append new data to a CSV file.

For example: I have 3 columns, namely, **Quantity**, **Cost**, **Item**.

And say, I have the following data:

- Quantity = 20
- Cost = 150
- Item = Keyboard

Each time I use the code, it should create a new row for the data - the output would look like:

```
Quantity,Cost,Item
20,150,Keyboard
20,150,Keyboard
```

Instead, the following code only produces the following output each time I run it:

```
Quantity,Cost,Item
20,150,Keyboard
```

Code:

```
QUANTITY = 20
COST = 150
ITEM = "Keyboard"

with open('orders.csv', 'w', newline='') as order_csv:
    order_csv_write = csv.writer(order_csv)
    order_csv_write.writerow(
        ["QUANTITY", "COST", "ITEM"])

with open('orders.csv', 'a', newline='') as order_csv:
    order_csv_append = writer(order_csv)
    order_csv_append.writerow([QUANTITY, COST, ITEM])
    order_csv.close()
```

How do I go about it the right way?

Comment: Uh, the first `open` obviously overwrites any previous contents.

Comment: You open the output file in 'w' mode. This will create a new file. You then open it with 'a' mode to append. What you probably want to do is to check if the file exists. If it exists don't open in 'w' mode and write the column heading just move on to append mode

Comment: That makes sense. The more I learn. Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you use the write `w` mode, it overwrites the file, deleting the old contents in the process.

It might make more sense to first check if the file exists, and write the header row only if it doesn't. Here's one way to do that, and it shows the behaviour required in your question:

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path


QUANTITY = 20
COST = 150
ITEM = "Keyboard"
FILE_PATH = Path('orders.csv')

if not FILE_PATH.exists():
    with open(FILE_PATH, 'w', newline='') as order_csv:
        order_csv_write = csv.writer(order_csv)
        order_csv_write.writerow(
            ["QUANTITY", "COST", "ITEM"])

with open(FILE_PATH, 'a', newline='') as order_csv:
    order_csv_append = csv.writer(order_csv)
    order_csv_append.writerow([QUANTITY, COST, ITEM])
```

Comment: Additionally, you don't have to call `order_csv.close()` when using `with ... as`, as it's handled automatically.

Comment: That wasn't my code, and you're right - I knew it wasn't necessary. Thanks a ton!